# Facebook SDK returned an error: No URL set

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I am trying to use Facebook SDK to connect to an app, but I get the error `Facebook SDK returned an error: No URL set`.

This is the code I am using to connect to Facebook:

```
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-sdk-v5/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '***',
  'app_secret' => '***',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
```

I already tried using different apps. I also activated server2server connections with my hosting provider.

What could be the reason of such error?

Comment: Wow. There are _still_ people developing for facebook? In 2015?

Comment: @arkascha I have to `D:`

Comment: So what do your app settings look like? What platforms do you have set up?

Comment: I think the message is asking you to add redirect url to your app in app dashboard.